# Editing a proof verification question to add a problem with said proof.

Tags: discussion

I have recently written a question on the main site ([The Riemann–Stieltjes Integral: Proving a Convergence Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4493876/438103)) that asked for a solution verification. On checking over the question I have found a potentially major problem with my proof that I cannot readily fix, but would be useful for other question readers to be aware of, but would require a couple of paragraphs of info at the end of the question.

Should I add this extra information to the question or put it into a separate answer. I ideally would like to put it into the question as it gives more direction to an open ended question. However, this may change the form of the question to be too different from that as original posted. Also: deleting and reposting seems overkill. Please advise on how to proceed.

Comment: Yes, when you are editing your own Question with an observation about the gap found in your solution, this makes sense.  I'm not clear how you think the observation changes it to be too different.  Of course if you have found a mistake in the solution, you could post it as a self-answer.

Comment: I haven't solved the error at the moment see. Cool, I will add as edit. (I know MathSE doesn't like too much editing to questions once made so I thought I would ask to check :))

Comment: If there are already answers, and if your edit would invalidate one or more of them, then there's a problem. Otherwise, I don't see a problem with making an edit.

Comment: Since you didnt get an answer, deleting and posting a new question seems like a good solution to me. Note that this is in your best interest, since your question will get additional attention and you can probably just copy most of the question.